# What is the usage of gcc subprograms cc1, cc1plus, as, ld and ar?

Tags: gcc, compilation

What is the usage of each gcc subprogram: cc1, cc1plus, as, ld and ar?
Is there any documentation of them?

Comment: `as`, `ld` en `ar` all have manpages.

Answer (score 3):

`cc1` and `cc1plus` are the C and C++ compilers.  For historical reasons, they are separate programs.  Their existence is completely internal to the compiler, and the interface with the compiler driver (`gcc`) can change at anytime, so it is best not to call them directly.

`as`, `ld`, and `ar` are part of [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/).